# push id, text in typescript string array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm using **ng2-select** in my angular2/4 app. the items data should be an array of objects with id and text properties. but when i push id and text

```
this.tagsItems.push({text: this.tags[i].name, id: this.tags[i]._id});
```

the error will be:

> Argument of type '{ text: any; id: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

My array:

```
public tagsItems: Array<string> = [];
```

when i change arrays type to any the error will gone but the ng2-select doesn't work anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you re not adding strings to your array as you've declared id.

you may declare an interface

```
Interface Text {
  text: String,
  id: Number|String // whatever this field should be
}
```

and then have tagsItems declared as this:

```
public tagsItems: Array<Text> = [];
```

Comment: always we should declare an interface?

Comment: If you don't want typescript to complain about this, yes. You may leave it as any if you wouldn t really use that interface elsewhere in your app